# Angularjs Directive not working with jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working on getting a jQuery UI date picker to work inside of an AngularJS 1.3 directive.  So far I have been able to get the date picker to render on the screen, and for the selected value to be displayed within the text box.  However, I am not able to pass the selected value back to the parent controller for use within in the application.

Here is my directive code.

```
angular.module("demo", []).directive('myDatepicker', function ($parse) {
   return {
      restrict: "E",
      replace: true,
      transclude: false,
      compile: function (element, attrs) {
         var modelAccessor = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
     var html = "<input type='text' id='" + attrs.id + "' >" +
        "</input>";

     var newElem = $(html);
     element.replaceWith(newElem);

     return function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {

        var processChange = function () {
           var date = new Date(element.datepicker("getDate"));

           scope.$apply(function (scope) {
              // Change bound variable
              modelAccessor.assign(scope, date);
           });
        };

        element.datepicker({
           inline: true,
           onClose: processChange,
           onSelect: processChange
        });

        scope.$watch(modelAccessor, function (val) {
           var date = new Date(val);
           element.datepicker("setDate", date);
        });

     };

  }
```

};
});

Comment: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ there is datepicker here, u can customize it if u need

Comment: I have looked at using there directive; however, I have not been able to get it work with AngularJS 1.3 .  There website claims that it works with AngularJS 1.2  The ultimate goal I have is to be able to use any jQuery UI component in an Angular Directive.

Comment: Thats interesting, because on that site there is cute link: Edit in Plunker, where u can change link to angular from 1.2 to 1.3.1 or 1.3.4 and it works...

Comment: Thanks, Petr I will check it out.

Comment: Petr,  I got it to work inside my application.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I suggest that you bring in angular material. They have a great date picker for use with Angular 1.3:

[Angular Material Form with Date Picker Demo](https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.input)

Comment: Thanks Sam.  I didn't know that this existed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use selected value within the application remember

> the selected value to be displayed within the text box

Get the value of input, it has the selected value of datepicker according to your words.

I suggest to read more about AngularJS, you will find out using $watch and $apply is not recomended for this kind of "simple" even "trivial" operations.

Comment: The problem is that I do not have access to the value that is displayed inside of the input field.  The pages controller does not see the value.  This is the issue that I am having.   Your answer does nothing to actually help me figure out how to fix the issue that I am having.